# Using Redux with React-Router-DOM Data Routers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-dom

Could I use Redux with routers in the following way? Also is there a reason to use it this way instead of using the router module's hooks?

```
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import HomePage from "./pages/HomePage";
import RootLayout from "./components/RootLayout";
import SearchPage from "./pages/SearchPage";
import WeatherPage from "./pages/WeatherPage";
import SettingsPage from "./pages/SettingsPage";
import { loader as HomePageLoader } from "./pages/HomePage";
import { useDispatch, useEffect } from "react-redux";

let router = "";

function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    router = createBrowserRouter([
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <RootLayout />,
        children: [
          {
            index: true,
            element: <HomePage />,
            loader: () => {
              HomePageLoader(dispatch);
            }
          },
          { path: "search", element: <SearchPage /> },
          { path: "weather", element: <WeatherPage /> },
          { path: "settings", element: <SettingsPage /> }
        ]
      }
    ]);
  }, []);

  return (
    <RouterProvider router={router}>
    </RouterProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure. But instead of using a `useEffect` hook to mutate a locally "global" `router` variable you should instead use the `useMemo` hook to just memoize the `router` and close over the `dispatch` function in scope.

Also, `useEffect` is not a `react-redux` export.

Example:

```
import { useMemo } from "react";
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import HomePage, { loader as homePageLoader } from "./pages/HomePage";
import RootLayout from "./components/RootLayout";
import SearchPage from "./pages/SearchPage";
import WeatherPage from "./pages/WeatherPage";
import SettingsPage from "./pages/SettingsPage";

function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const router = useMemo(() => {
    return createBrowserRouter([
      {
        path:"/",
        element: <RootLayout />,
        children: [
          {
            index: true,
            element: <HomePage />,
            loader: homePageLoader(dispatch),
          }
          { path: "search", element: <SearchPage /> },
          { path: "weather", element: <WeatherPage /> },
          { path: "settings", element: <SettingsPage /> }
        ]
      }
    ]);
  }, [dispatch]);

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default App;
```

Ensure that `homePageLoader` is a curried function so it can be passed the `dispatch` function and return a function that is passed the loader props.

Example:

```js
const loader = dispatch => ({ params, request }) => {
  // loader logic
};
```

Comment: could I make the loader function anonymous and then call the actual loader function logic inside it?
also, is there any reason to use redux or am i just over complicating it?

Comment: @Ragnar Probably, but could you clarify better what you mean by "anonymous loader function"? They generally tend to be specific to the route they load. Any reason to use Redux, sure if you want/need a single global state and an easy, dependable, and synchronous way to manage and reason about state and its updates. The question about overcomplicating it depends on the overall app complexity though. If you had a simple timer app for example, then Redux is probably overkill, but generally speaking, Redux becomes more useful the bigger the app and state become.

Comment: i mean a function that would be passed on like this:
loader: () => {  loaderfunc(dispatch); }
thanks for the help btw

Comment: @Ragnar You could do that, sure, but then your `loaderfunc` wouldn't be able to take advantage of the `Route` [loader](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/loader)'s props, e.g. route `params` and the `request` object, and this is a bit more verbose if you needed to pass them through or return a value from `loaderfunc`. If you don't need to do any of this then perhaps a route loader isn't the best place for the `loaderfunc` call, you could just the `useDispatch` and `useEffect` hooks in the routed component instead.